# Работа с содержимым блока contenteditable=true

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте,подскажите,как быть.
есть блок `<div id="c" contenteditable=true></div>`
реально ли сделать,что бы при вводе туда тегов,они были там в виде **таком**, а не `<strong>таком</strong>` 
P.s. wysiwyg не интересуют.
Спасибо!

Comment: Отслеживайте нажатия клавиш в этом блоке и после, например, нажатия клавиши Enter переводите введенный текст в html теги, но вам проще использовать сторонние библиотеки, где уже реализован данный функционал.

Answer (score 1):

***Можно еще так обёртывать в теги*** http://jsfiddle.net/88NAw/15/

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.wrapSelected = function(open, close) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      var selectedText = selection.extractContents();

      var tagname = $(open + close);
      tagname[0].appendChild(selectedText);
      selection.insertNode(tagname[0]);

      if (selectedText.childNodes[1] != undefined) {
        console.log(selectedText.childNodes[1]);
        $(selectedText.childNodes[1]).remove();
      }
    });

  }
})(jQuery);

$("#strong").click(function() {
  $("#message").wrapSelected('<strong>', '</strong>');
});
```